# Compare rows and remove previous row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a df that looks like

| username | amount | verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amy123 | 25 | no |
| bob1 | 25 | yes |
| amy123 | 26 | yes |
| bob1 | 40 | yes |
| bob1 | 41 | yes |

wondering how I can compare the amount and if the amount difference is <=1 and only if the previous row is the same user, i will keep the bigger number  the final df will look like:

| username | amount | verified |
| --- | --- | --- |
| amy123 | 25 | no |
| bob1 | 25 | yes |
| amy123 | 26 | yes |
| bob1 | 41 | yes |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can groupby and mask the dataframe on two conditions using (1) .shift() to compare with previous 'username' and (2) .diff() to handle the difference in 'amount'

```
#import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create the df
d = {'username': ['amy123', 'bob1', 'amy123', 'bob1', 'bob1'],
     'amount': [25,25,26,40,41],
     'verified': ['no','yes','yes','yes','yes']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)

#mask the df on two conditions 
df[((df['username'].shift() == df['username']) &  #keep if above user is the same
     (df.groupby('username')['amount'].diff() <= 1))] #keep if difference is less than or equal to 1
```

Comment: hi! this kinda works but what if my first row is username: 'amy123' amount: 24 and second row is username: 'amy123' amount 25? it seems like it keeps the first row when it should be removed.

Comment: Hi!  Good catch since the difference seems to be more important, we can move that condition to be after the .first() condition.  Will updated answer to reflect

Comment: ^ actually this leaves similar issues due to the OR condition... let me look into it further

Comment: so the .first() condition was wrong to use.  You're gonna want to go with that .shift() function to make the comparison with the above 'username'.  Updated answer to reflect... please let me know if it's still not working as desired!

Answer (score 2):

You can compute masks for the difference in amount and the change in user and use it to `groupby` and get the max:

```
# is the difference > 1?
m1 = df['amount'].diff().gt(1)
# has the user changed?
m2 = df['username'].ne(df['username'].shift())

# keep rows matching either condition with the max amount
(df.groupby((m1|m2).cumsum(), group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('amount').tail(1))
 )
```

output:

```
  username  amount verified
0  amy123       25       no
1    bob1       25      yes
2  amy123       26      yes
4    bob1       41      yes
```

Comment: @Mustafa no my solution was incorrect, I had neglected the max value condition ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the next entry using shift(-1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'username': ['amy123', 'bob1', 'amy123', 'bob1', 'bob1'],
    'amount': [25,25,26,40,41],
    'verified': ['no','yes','yes','yes','yes']}
)

df = df[~((df["username"] == df["username"].shift(-1))
 & (df["amount"].shift(-1) - df["amount"] <= 1))]
```

`~` is "not", `shift(-1)` the next entry